# Put form image into array (VB .net)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, screenshot, shapes

I put two solid circles (shapes) onto a form, change their colors, and move them around. When I get them into the right position, I want to capture the full-color image of the form and put it into an array as quickly as possible. How can I do this?

Here is how I draw the objects:
I get an OvalShape from VB PowerPacks in VB2010Express and draw it as a circle on the form. After that, I adjust it in code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OccultSize1 = 100
    OccultSize2 = 50
    OvalShape1.Width = OccultSize1
    OvalShape1.Height = OccultSize1
    OvalShape2.Width = OccultSize2
    OvalShape2.Height = OccultSize2
    OvalShape1.Left() = 155 - OvalShape1.Width / 2
    OvalShape1.Top() = 153 - OvalShape1.Height / 2
    OvalShape2.Left() = 155 - OvalShape2.Width / 2
    OvalShape2.Top = 85  'temporary
    OvalShape1.FillColor = Color.Yellow
    OvalShape1.BorderColor = Color.Yellow
    OvalShape2.FillColor = Color.Blue
    OvalShape2.BorderColor = OvalShape2.FillColor
    Label1.Text = "100"
    Label2.Text = "50"
    Label3.Text = "xxx"
    tbHue.Value = OvalShape2.FillColor.GetHue
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton2.Checked = True
    LineShape1.Visible = False
    LineShape2.Visible = True
    OvalShape3.Visible = False
  End Sub
```

Here is what I have tried with DrawToBitmap (copied most of it from Stack Overflow): Button1.Click is my addition.

```
Private Function GetFormImage(ByRef GetBitmap As String) As Bitmap
    ' Make the bitmap.
    Dim wid As Integer = Me.Width
    Dim hgt As Integer = Me.Height
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(wid, hgt)
    ' Draw the form onto the bitmap.
    Me.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt))
    bm.Save("E:\rhtempsave\bm.bmp")
    ' Make a smaller bitmap without borders.
    wid = 240 'Me.ClientSize.Width
    hgt = 320 'Me.ClientSize.Height
    Dim bm2 As New Bitmap(wid, hgt)
    ' Get the offset from the window's corner to its client
    ' area's corner.
    Dim pt As New Point(0, 0)
    pt = PointToScreen(pt)
    Dim dx As Integer = 37 'pt.X - Me.Left
    Dim dy As Integer = 10 'pt.Y - Me.Top
    ' Copy the part of the original bitmap that we want
    ' into the bitmap.
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm2)
    gr.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, New Rectangle(dx, dy, wid, hgt), _
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    bm2.Save("E:\rhtempsave\bm2.bmp")
    Return bm2
End Function
```

[This is bm2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLo3P.png)

Comment: [**Control.DrawToBitmap**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent. I mean I want to capture the image of the form AND the shapes as they appear on the form. I presume your suggestion gets the image into a bitmap and from there I have to put the bitmap into an array--I think I can do that, but first the bitmap. I have a line: Me.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0,0,wid,hgt)) with everything declared and then I save the file, which turns out to be tiny and not visible in Photoshop. Dimensions are 240x320 so the file should be bigger than 11 bytes. There must be a million examples of this on the web, I just haven't found them.

Comment: I understood you wanted that. `DrawToBitmap()` will do the trick in some cases, but the actual answer to your question differs depending on how you draw the shapes. It would be best if you showed us your code. As for your attempt, you haven't shown how the `wid` and `hgt` variables are declared nor how you save the resulted bitmap. Please edit your question to include details (preferably code) about how you draw your shapes and also your attempts using `DrawToBitmap()`.

Comment: This is how I draw an object:

Comment: DO NOT post your code in comments! Edit your question by pressing `Edit` below it. Include your drawing code, your `DrawToBitmap()` attempt, and if possible the output of your DrawToBitmap attempt.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the bitmaps appeared on my disk today, but not yesterday. The only thing I did in the meantime was shutdown and restart my computer. Strangely, the bmps are not readable by Photoshop, Photoshop Elements or Win10's photo reader yet they show up as icons in the disk file dialog. Probably a header problem. I think I'm good to go with the next step of putting the bmp into an array for later retrieval. Thanks. I'm very grateful for your prompt response.

Comment: No problem. If you want an image of the form without the border you could dock-fill a panel in the form and put everything inside it instead. Then you just draw a bitmap of that entire panel.

Comment: As for your problem with opening the images, try specifying the format when saving. For example: `bm2.Save("E:\rhtempsave\bm2.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)`. If that doesn't work try PNG instead.

Comment: Finally, arrays aren't that hard actually. Just declare an array: `Dim Images(2 - 1) As Bitmap 'An array containing 2 bitmaps.` then set a bitmap in it: `Images(0) = bm2` **(`0` is the first item in the array, `1` is the second and so on)**. You might also want to consider a [**List(Of T)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're going to add an indefinite amount of images. A list works similar to an array, but it will resize itself automatically as you add more items (done via `YourList.Add(bm2)`).

Comment: This is very helpful. The array I want to construct is an array of RGB pixels, or maybe an array each of the R,G, and B values. Then I will pull out the R, G, and B value for each pixel and send it out to a display. I figure this is quicker than Get from the bitmap. Thanks again!